# Set enviroment variable with y/n in makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to implement a question in my makefile. So how can I ask the user whether he wants to build the binary with or without the LEDs on/off.

When the user starts "make" in the shell there should be a question like "Do you want to build your Binary with LED implemented? y/n"

If there is a "n" my preprocessor should ignore all LED implementations in my c program. The part in c I already did. But I'm new with makefiles.

Could I set a env.variable via my makefile? And HOW could I do this?

Comment: I think you'd be better off with a shell script that asks the questions and then passes the appropriate variables to Make.

Answer (score 3):

How about separate targets, so you could have the user utter

```
$ make with-led
```

or

```
$ make no-led
```

Then your targets could use the appropriate preprocessor flags with ease.

Comment: Or alternatively: `make WITH_LED=1` / `make WITH_LED=0`. But interactive `make` sounds awful.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't claim it's a good idea.  But it is possible:

```
# For GNU Make

ifndef LEDS
LEDS := $(shell bash -c 'read -p "Use LEDS? [y/n] " && echo $$REPLY')
endif

print:
    @echo LEDS=$(LEDS)
```

I really recommend that you re-think whether that's what you want.  On of the principles of Make is that it's not interactive, and users of your build will likely not thank you for violating that.  For example, automated compilation on a build server, or simply in an Emacs `compile` buffer.

A better strategy is to default one way or the other in a Make variable - this can be overridden when invoking Make:

```sh
make install LED=0
```

You could possibly insist that a value is specified:

```
# GNU Make, again

ifndef LEDS
$(error LEDS must be specified for this build)
endif
```

Comment: Sure you could do that, but one of the basic concepts of make is that it is for hands off operation - so interaction with the user outside of command line options is not something I'd recommend.

Comment: Yes, I should have been stronger with my "not a good idea" introduction.